# Centos 7: Multiple virtual host is not working

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost, vhosts

My server information is

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 19 2015 21:43:13
```

I am trying to configure virtual host for 2 different sites: biz.example.com and pin.example.com which are hosted on the same server. There are 2 different folders located under 'var/www/html/' named 'biz' and 'pin' with their respected project files for the above mentioned 2 websites. I am trying to configure it on the below way.

Within /etc/hosts below configuration

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx biz.example.com
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx pin.example.com
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is replaced by the server IP address.

Within  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Now, under /etc/httpd/sites-available there are biz.conf and pin.conf file. I also have the folder sites-enabled under /etc/httpd which has 2 files that points to the biz.conf and pin.conf of sites-available folder using the below command

```
ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/biz.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/biz.conf

ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/pin.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/pin.conf
```

biz.conf has the followings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://biz.example.com/
ServerAlias http://biz.example.com/
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/biz"
<directory "/var/www/html/biz">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the configuration within pin.conf file is mentioned as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://pin.example.com/
ServerAlias http://pin.example.com/
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pin"
<directory "/var/www/html/pin">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On this setup, if i try to access http://biz.example.com/ , the correct website (biz website) is loading. But if i try to access http://pin.example.com/ , then also biz website is loading instead of pin website. Multiple configuration is not working together.

I also tried to merge the virtual configuration of biz.conf and pin.conf within a single file, biz.conf, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Are there any other `.conf` files in `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/`? Are there any VirtualHosts defined in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`?

Comment: @DusanBajic: No for both the question.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slashes form `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` (in fact you don't need ServerAlias at all since it is the same as ServerName)

Comment: Wow... it worked after trailing slashes and removing ServerAlias. Thanks @DusanBajic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) directive is:

```
ServerName [scheme://]domain-name|ip-address[:port]
```

without the trailing slash. As a side effect, since ServerName is not recognized, the first VirtualHost is always served.